# Conditional order in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to check the condition in Angular.
I want to look at two numbers that would enter Div if these two numbers were equal.
How can I check this condition?
I tried the following method and it was wrong.

```
<div *ngIf="'{{item1.menuID==item2.menuID}}'">
    {{item1.title}}
  </div>
```

Comment: *ngIf="'item1.menuID==item2.menuID'"

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to use interpolation within [anyAttributeEnclosingSquareBrackets] or any angular attribute like *ngIf, *ngFor or some attributes like formControlName

For example:

```
<child-component [childAttribute]="parentComponentVariable">
<div *ngFor="let x of arrayVariable">Array Variable is present in component</div>
<input type="text" formControlName="name">
```

You can directly compare like below code:

```
<div *ngIf="item1.menuID==item2.menuID">
    {{item1.title}}
</div>
```

Assuming that, item1 and item2 are not private variables of component and are available or initialise expectedly

Comment: Thanks. My problem is solved
Your explanation was complete

Comment: @Aliakbar. If it help then you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there would evaluate to a string given you're adding single quotes around the condition, also you don't need to interpolate to access an object inside an ngIf.

If you want to evaluate if `item1.menuID` and `item2.menuID` are equal you would do

`<div *ngIf="item1.menuID == item2.menuID">
    {{item1.title}}
</div>`